# SQL join should display only one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables in which i need to display FL_AmmendmentDetails table on join of user_id but in 2nd table i have two data with same user_id so its displaying two data i need to display only one data> Here only user_id is common in both Table

```
select FA.App_Name,FLA.ammendment_status,FA.App_Concern,FA.Respo_Mob,FLA.RegNo,FA.user_id
from FL_AmmendmentDetails as FLA 
left join FL_Form_A1 as FA on FA.user_id = FLA.user_id 
where FLA.RegNo='FE19-2006329'
```

Table 1

```
select * from FL_AmmendmentDetails where RegNo='FE19-2006329'
```

Table 2

```
select * from FL_Form_A1 where user_id=23405
```

[image]

Comment: Which one you want to see?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data (and expected result) as formatted text, not as images. And I can't read that tiny image text.

Comment: Isn't RegNo common between the two tables? RegNo on FL_AmmendmentDetails and Reg_No on FL_Form_A1

Comment: Your screenshot suggests `SQL Server` management tool. `MySQL` <> `SQL Server`.

Comment: @Jens i want to see FL_AmmendmentDetails table data

Comment: @Rob no RegNo is not common here only user_id matches in both table

Comment: You haven't really answered Jens' question. You say you want to show one result row per user. But there are two rows for the same user in `FL_Form_A1`. So, which of the two rows do you want to select? What rule do you want to apply to pick this one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select FA.App_Name,FLA.ammendment_status,FA.App_Concern,FA.Respo_Mob,FLA.RegNo,FA.user_id,
             row_number() over (partition by FLA.user_id order by fa.RegNo desc) as seq
      from FL_AmmendmentDetails as FLA left join 
           FL_Form_A1 as FA 
           on FA.user_id = FLA.user_id 
      where fla. . . . .;
     ) t 
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: how to use FLA in where condition

Comment: @chethu. . . In Subquery you can include `where` clause.